# dpa 2006c or senn 8020?

Tags: field-recording, omni, ambiance, background, microphone

Hey everyone,

I am in the market for a pair of compact omnis for BG recording. I am looking specifically at the DPA 2006c or Sennheiser 8020. The 8020 set is about 600 more than the dpa's though, you're getting better frequency response and lower self-noise with that money. What do you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a pair of DPA 2006Cs and am reasonably happy with them, but they're not quite as versatile as I'd hoped.

Be warned if you're looking to make field recordings in very quiet surroundings, like wilderness areas, mountain, moorland etc. DPA claim an A-weighted self-noise of 16dB, but also note a maximum level of 18dBA. I found it intrusive recently when recording in the Scottish Highlands, to the point that I only used the recordings made with an AT BP4025 single-point stereo mic taken along as backup.

This soundmap I put together uses a headworn pair of DPA 2006Cs for nearly all of its recordings made in and around London:

[London Sound Survey waterways soundmap](http://www.soundsurvey.org.uk/index.php/survey/waterways/)

If you can afford the Sennheisers, why not go for them instead? I would have done so if I'd had the money, not getting them was maybe a false economy. Otherwise the Neumann KM183 might be worth considering. It's just under 11cm long, which is fairly compact.

Cheers
Ian